# How to use 2x$$ together linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, unix

the questing is how to use two variables togheter..

ex.
**$1,$2,$3** are set

```
numb=2
```

I need to use command:

```
head $$numb
```

that must be the same as:

```
head $2
```

I tried everything, I need to know what to put between `$` and `$numb` so the output shows me the 10 first lines of `$2`

like `head $"$numb"` or `head $'\$numb\'`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you just do `head $2` or `numb=$2; head $numb`? Please explain the rest of your script's structure, there will be other ways of doing what you need. Also, this is off topic here, you might want to flag for moderator attention and ask them to migrate to [unix.se] or [so].

Comment: i set a text file (that contains locations of another files) to variables with command `set 'less myfile'`
so every line of that file is `$1,$2,$3`... etc. then i set number of lines with command `numb=$#`  .... gonna use also those commands:
`while [ $numb -gt 0 ]`
`do head $"$numb"`
`numb=$[$numb-1]`
so gonna make the script
show the first then lines of every file. so the head $"$numb" not working as i wish, need help here

Comment: OK, that is a really way too complex (and wrong, as you saw) way of doing this. See my answer for an easier method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading through all your comments, I address only your initial question.

In `bash`the operator for variable indirection is `!`, see this simple example script `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
bar=2
echo "${!bar}"
```

As a side note: In (my favorite shell) `zsh` you can use the *Parameter Expansion Flag `P`* to get this result

```
#!/bin/zsh
bar=2
echo "${(P)bar}"
```

But you can also use a different approach, the third line may also read `echo "${@[$bar]}"`. 
Here you can think of `"$@"` as an array of `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`, hence `"${@[2]}"` is equivalent to `"$2"`.

However, both `foo` scripts produce the same result:

```
$ ./foo one two three
two
```

Comment: wow that actually is what i was looking for for my first script thanx a lot ${!bar} did everything =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/env/bash

files=$1

while IFS= read -r name;
do
  head "$name";
done < "$files"
```

Then, you run the script with the file containing the file names of interest (one per line) as an argument:

```
./foo.sh files.txt
```

The `while` loop saves each file name from `files.txt` as `$name` and then runs `head` on it.

Comment: Ok thanx that works, but i need the script to open the file that contains paths by itself and read the head of each file one by one, that why i was playing with those variables..so i want use a command after seeing the head of each file to remove it with the options yes and no...so its sort of script that will clean my directory so i was maybe thinking to use the `case` command for options

Comment: @Denis you can do that with my example. Just change `files=$1`to `files=/path/to/files.txt`. Then, add the `delete Y/N` or whatever, after the `head` command inside the loop. The file name is `$name` and you can delete with `rm $name`. Next time, for this kind of thing, post on [unix.se] or [so].

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
echo "Give directory to search for ASCII text files"
read direct
find $direct -type f -exec file {} + | grep ASCII > ztextz
sed "s/ .*//" ztextz > ztextz1
sed "s/://g" ztextz1 > ztextz2
#lets try
files=ztextz2
while IFS= read -r name;
do
head "$name";
echo "Do you want to delete this file?"
read want
case $want in
YES)
rm $name;;
Yes)
rm $name;;
yes)
rm $name;;
Y)
rm $name;;
y)
rm $name;;
esac
done < "$files"`

here is my script with yours. it searches for ASCII files and writes them in a file. Then it shows you head of first text file and ask if you want to delete and then next

Comment: but still it doesnt work=( PS. sorry if i posted in a wrong place, its just my first post here... **PSSS. and tell me how to write the script here as a script not as a text like i did**

Comment: @Denis please update your question to add new info, it is impossible to read and easy to miss in the comments. As for posting in the wrong place, don't worry, I know you did not do it on purpose, just letting you know for next time. However, since this question is likely to be closed here, flag it for mod attention and ask a mod to migrate it to [unix.se]. I'm active there too so we can pick up where we left off. In the meantime, add what you have to your question and specify _how_ it fails and what errors you get.